# "Housing invalid" Terraria XBOX 360

Tags: terraria-console

I have a castle in the sky. It is made completely out of stone bricks and walls. I have met ALL the requirements necessary and am still told it is not valid. I have 6 rooms in the upper part of my castle, 3 on the left-which are completely symmetrical to the 3 on the right. The rooms in the top corners are (from the inside of the walls) 7x4. The roomes in the middle are ("  ") 8x4. And the rooms on the bottom are ("  ") 10x4.

The top rooms are high enough that it just barely starts to turn into space and while that *could* be the problem, Steve the Guide used to live in the upper left corner. I left that world and when I came back, Steve was in a different room and his old one said it was invalid. The one right below it is also having problems even though I have Durim the demolitionist in the room on the opposite side.

Like I previously mentioned, I made the rooms on the right *completely* identical to the ones on the left. Complete with stone brick, stone walls (of which I went over again), 1 torch, 1 chair, 1 table/workbench and plenty of floor space. I don't have any platforms  in the rooms and yes I have a door leading to each one. Thanks in advance for your help! :)